# Update Table1 if no referencing row in TABLE2 exists, limit updates

Tags: sql, postgresql

The PK of table1 is a FK in table2.

I wish to update the status in table1 where no record exists in table2 and limit the number of updates. There may be no records in table2.

Something like:

```
UPDATE t1
SET status = 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id
    FROM t2
    WHERE t1.id = t2.id
    LIMIT 1000
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little complicated in Postgres, because there is no `limit`.  Assuming that you have a primary key in `t1` (which I'll assume is `id`), you can use a subquery to determine the rows to update and then match in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET status = 0
    FROM (SELECT tt1.*
          FROM t1 tt1
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.id FROM t2 WHERE tt1.id = t2.id)
          LIMIT 1000
         ) ttl
    WHERE t1.id = tt1.id;
```

Comment: Thanks worked a treat, I just needed to add an alias to the subquery which I have submitted an edit for

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this under **concurrent write load**, there is a **race condition** between the subquery (the `SELECT` to determine rows) and the outer `UPDATE`, which can lead to wrong results. To defend against this, add a row locking clause.

However, this needs to be done in a CTE to be reliable (at least in my test wit Postgres up to version 10). So:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT id      -- PK
   FROM   t1
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
   LIMIT  1000
   FOR    UPDATE  -- SKIP LOCKED -- ?
   )
UPDATE t1
SET    status = 0
FROM   cte
WHERE  t1.id = cte.id
RETURNING id;     -- optional
```

If you run multiple commands like this, possibly in parallel, add `SKIP LOCKED`, so that they don't block each other.

This only secures existing rows in `t1`. There is still the problem that conflicting rows might be added in `t2` between `SELECT` and `UPDATE`.

You mentioned a FK constraint. I am not sure from the top of my head whether depending rows in `t2` are blocked from being added by the FK constraint while there is a `FOR UPDATE` lock on the parent row. Would have to test, but out of time right now.

Postgres has no predicate-locking for user commands. (Users can only lock existing rows.) To be absolutely sure, you could also use the (more expensive) `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation.

See:

- [Postgres UPDATE … LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497)